# Java abstract class, Interface, method Overriding

Tags: java, oop, abstract-class, overriding

Hello I am confusion on the method implements so please any one help me?
following are my scenario

I have one abstract class

```
public abstract class VehicalAbstarct {

    public abstract void speed();
}
```

I have one interface

```
public interface Vehical {

    public void speed();
}
```

I have one more class which extends **VehicalAbstarct** and implemnts **Vehical** interface

```
public class VehicalExample extends VehicalAbstarct implements Vehical {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        VehicalExample v=new VehicalExample();
        v.speed();
    }

    @Override
    public void speed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Speed is calling from vehical example..");
    }

}

***********OUTPUT************
Speed is calling from vehical example..
```

Now **speed()** method is @Override by **VehicalAbstarct** class or @Override by **Vehical** interface?

If @Override by **VehicalAbstarct** class then how?
and
@Override by **Vehical** interface then how?

Comment: Ok, when somebody links you to another question, you should read it and say whether it answers your question. I think the accepted answer addresses what you are asking - you are overriding both. Same as if you implemented two separate interfaces that had a method name in common.

Answer (score 1):

You override the method in `VehicalAbstarct` which overrides the method in the `Vehical` interface. So, in a way you override both of them.

See this example:

```
interface A {
    default void method() {
    }
}

abstract class B {
    abstract void method();
}

class C extends B implements A {
    // compiler error, method() not implemented
}
```

Even though `A` has a default implementation of `method()`, it's overridden by `B` with an abstract one. Therefore we have to override it in `C`.